# Angular SEO: Google Webmaster Tools and Prerender.io in Node.js server on Heroku

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gwt, seo, prerender

After following docs and tutorials about setting up a prerender.io server on heroku, GWT is still fetching and rendering my site without data.

prerender.io is caching the pages properly, I've set the fragment meta tag in index.html, and $locationProvider.hashPrefix('!') in my app.js.

Can anyone please explain what's necessary to get the site crawled properly or if what GWT renders is not as applicable as it seems?

Thanks!

Here's the express server

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'MYTOKEN'));

var prerender = require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://blooming-brushlands-2690.herokuapp.com/');
app.use(prerender);
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Google fetches just fine but to see what it sees in GWT's Fetch as Google:

**YOURBASEURL/?_escaped_fragment_=/RESTOFTHEURL**

Turns out, GWT was crawling appropriately with prerender.io's hosting so after removing the self-hosted bits:

```
var prerender = require('prerender-node').set('prerenderServiceUrl', 'http://blooming-brushlands-2690.herokuapp.com/');
app.use(prerender);
```

And the rest of web.js being:

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use(require('prerender-node').set('prerenderToken', 'MYTOKEN'));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

GWT fetches and renders appropriately. If you want to view the properly fetched and rendered results you should use 
**YOURBASEURL/?_escaped_fragment_=/RESTOFTHEURL**
in GWT's Fetch as Google.

Big ups to Todd at Prerender.io for helping out with this.